# Permitir Múltiplos Providers com Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando implementar o permissionamento por Roles dentro da minha controller:

```
   [PerfilFiltro(Roles = "Administrador,Caixa")]
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Adicional.ToList());
    }
```

```
 public class PerfilFiltro : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Negado");
    }


}
```

Eu quero fazer da seguinte forma:
*Os perfis Administrador OU caixa podem abrir o Index.
 O que acontece quando eu coloco entre virgulas é que a role do usuário logado deve ser administrador E caixa, mas eu quero administrador OU caixa.

Comment: Isso é meio estranho... era para estar funcionando. Teste sem a classe PerfilFiltro. Use o Authorize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente está tudo ok, mas por via das dúvidas, se quiser testar o comportamento da validação, experimente reimplementar o método `AuthorizeCore` e faça um debug dentro dele:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    return isAuthorized;
}
```

Aliás, você pode modificar esse método e implementar o comportamento que quiser, caso julgue necessário.

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer um teste também somente com o Authorize conforme o @Daniloloko sugeriu, mas acho que não seja isso. Eu pesquisei e em alguns sites como esse:http://devbrasil.net/profiles/blogs/autentica-o-e-permiss-es-de-usu-rios-em-asp-net-mvc-4 que dizem que quando coloca a Role entre vírgulas o usuário deve possuir todas as roles digitadas para acessar o controller e não é isso que eu quero.

Comment: @crs0794 Não necessariamente. Tenho uns 3 sistemas que usam o `[Authorize]` e todos trabalham com conjunção ("ou"), não como disjunção ("e"), mas enfim, faça o teste.

Comment: Obrigada, funcionou!! Não estava gravando o usuário logado no método SetAuthCookie por falta de uma configuração no web.config

Comment: @crs0794 Fique à vontade para alterar minha resposta e colocar essa configuração.